# Is there a word 'configurability'?

Tags: single-word-requests

If one is looking for a word meaning 'the capability of being configured", is 'configurability' acceptable?

The Oxford Online Dictionary, as well as other dictionaries, have [configurable](http://com) but not configurability.

Comment: With [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/13106/configurability), it's still at the 'candidate' stage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Yes, it should have its own full entry. Usage is increasing as shown below.

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary defines [configurability:](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/configurability) as:

> The property of being configurable.
>
> 2016, Yang Liu, Chris Dwyer, Alvin R. Lebeck, “Combined Compute and Storage: Configurable Memristor Arrays to Accelerate Search”, in arXiv‎:
>
> - *Furthermore, **the configurability of memristor arrays** and the proposed data structures provide opportunities to tune the trade-off between performance and lifetime and the data structures can be easily adapted to future memristors or other technologies with improved endurance.*

and [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=configurability&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconfigurability%3B%2Cc0) shows a rising trend in its usage, apparently in tech/scientific contexts.